# How to change a Javascript nested object in object to an indexed array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm fairly new to developing, so need some help with an object. I tried doing a for loop and pushing the values into an array. The problem is that it is pushing all the keys/values as one index rather than indexing each key/value separately. I am working with a key/value object as follows:

```
var obj = {
   "application": {
      "create": "false",
      "read": "true",
      "update": "true",
      "delete": "false"
   },
   "connection": {
      "create": "false",
      "read": "true",
      "update": "true",
      "delete": "false"
   }
}
```

I need each key(application and connection) to be indexed - the keys need to be values. For example the following would retrieve:

```
  obj[0] = application
  obj[0].create = false
  obj[1] = connection
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: please add the wanted (valid) result.

Comment: Why do you think you need this? Which problem are you trying to solve with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an extra field `key` to store the keys of the object `obj`. This is produce an `array` of objects.

```js
var obj = {
  "application": {
    "create": "false",
    "read": "true",
    "update": "true",
    "delete": "false"
  },
  "connection": {
    "create": "false",
    "read": "true",
    "update": "true",
    "delete": "false"
  }
}

var keys = Object.keys(obj)
var arr = []
keys.map(function(key, i) {
  arr[i] = obj[key]
  arr[i].key = key
})

console.log(arr[0].key)
console.log(arr[0].create)
console.log(arr[1].key)
```

Comment: Thanks, Pranesh. How can I achieve this with an object - it doesn't have to be an array. I just assumed it had to be an array.

Comment: @Heather Updated the answer. Check!

Comment: @Heather Awesome! consider up voting the answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you want each property of the object pushing into an array, you can iterate over the object contents like so:

```
for (var item in obj){
    /* item will equal the first property of obj, in this case: 'application' */
    array.push(item)
}

array = ["application", "connection"]
```

You can use the same technique on each object property, to index their children into the array.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. I'll try this. Can you provide a way how I can add the children?
I used Object.getOwnPropertyNames to push the keys into an array but I need to push the nested object as well.

Comment: You're welcome, can I ask, what your desired result is? You mentioned in another comment that you thought the result must be an array. If we know what your desired result is, then we can more provide a more accurate solution.

Comment: I am trying to populate a grid with this data. The headers of the table are Model, create, read, update, delete. The model column needs to populate with application and connection. The respective create, read, update, and delete values need to be populated for each model.

Answer (score 0):

By the outcome you expect, it looks like you want to transform the first level of your object to array cells.

This will do it:

```
var arr = [], i=0;
for (var key in obj) {
   arr[key] = obj[key] // For accessing via the property name for example e.g. application
   arr[i] = obj[key] // For index access for example obj[0]
   i++;
}
```

You can also use the .map method to do it.

Comment: Where does `i` come from? Why are you creating an array instead of just extending `obj` with numeric keys?

Comment: You are right i forgot to set it, i updated the example.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the keys and assamble a new array with the children of the inner object.

```js
var obj = { application: { create: "false", read: "true", update: "true", delete: "false" }, connection: { create: "false", read: "true", update: "true", delete: "false" } },
    array = Object.keys(obj).map(function (k) {
        return [k].concat(Object.keys(obj[k]).map(function (kk) {
            return obj[k][kk];
        }));
    });

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Thanks Nina. This indexes - however, I still need to retain the keys (application and connection). The console log is printing [0] object.

Comment: please add the wanted complete result in your question. as it is written, it is not valid javascript.